How does "vacuum where datname = current_database()" work?
From the documentation, it looks like you can specify a table name with the VACUUM command. The doc does not say how this command works with a where clause. Is it that vacuum where datname = current_database() vacuums the current database?

I don't see vacuum where ... shown as valid syntax in those documents. Also, it doesn't work when I try it (and honestly datname doesn't look legit either as any kind of keyword). Are you saying this command vacuum where datname = current_database() works? (although assuming it did, I can only imagine it would vacuum the specified database - what else?)

Well it doesn't work on my local either, but I do see this query in a customer's logs: vacuum where datname = current_database() /*pghero*/ and nothing like this in pghero's repo..

@Zegarek You only need FULL when you want to rewrite every table and index. Usually you don't want this, just VACUUM is good enough. On the other hand, autovacuum should do it's work in the background, it just might need some configuration for your workload.

@Zegarek Are you saying that VACUUM WHERE … is a custom command of some postgres extension?

@Bergi I'm not.

@FrankHeikens Sorry for leaving the comment up - the answer I ended up editing it into is without the full keyword.

It's an RDBMS-specific command, so it follows custom PostgreSQL syntax, rather that what you can expect from SQL standard DML commands like SELECT/DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT. It's just VACUUM table_name(column_name);. To vacuum the whole database, you can run vacuum; while being connected to it, with nothing following the command. The doc you linked says:

Without a table_and_columns list, VACUUM processes every table and materialized view in the current database

If you're asking about specifying the db, it might be because other RDBMS call a database what's effectively a schema or a namespace in PostgreSQL. Beyond DDL, like creating, dropping, altering databases, you can't really affect them unless you're connected to them directly.
